# REST design for checking boolean property of a resource

Tags: rest

My application provides the following resource:

```
GET /user/:id/orders
```

As commonly used, this returns a list of all the user's orders.

Now, a client wants to check if a user has any orders at all without actually getting the complete list.

My current approach looks like this:

```
GET /user/:id/orders/exist
```

But it looks kind of odd to me.

Is there a more "standard" way of designing this? In the end, this resource only needs to return the information:

- yes, user has orders
- no, user doesn't have any orders

Comment: You question title does not really match the question content. The question matches similar questions already asked - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/what-s-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object for example.

Comment: Consider a HEAD request (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) with a header indicating collection size. Alternately, consider returning the results in an envelope. Make one property of the envelope the total collection size. Permit a query parameter to specify the number of results to return. Clients can call GET with zero results and get the envelope containing the total number of records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a more "standard" way of designing this?

By default, REST focuses on returning resources themselves, rather than specific validation results involving those resources. So no, there's no real standardized way for this.

That being said, many REST APIs tend to somewhat deviate from pure REST, so it's not unreasonable to implement a feature like the one you've been asked to implement.

However, keeping in line with resource-based approaches and not action-based approaches, I would suggest keeping this as consistent as possible. Instead of:

```
GET /user/:id/orders/exist => returns boolean
```

I'd be more inclined to do:

```
GET /user/:id/orders/count => returns int
```

It still achieves the same goal (telling you if any exist or not), but the API sticks to a more resource-oriented semantic with the second approach.

That being said, from a technical perspective either approaches are equally viable.